# First big project using vanilla js and pure css

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

If i can get a some reviews and suggestion on the code it would be highly appreciated.

( Please check the flowchart i've created first https://github.com/chetinn/Memory-Map-JS/blob/main/Memory%20Map%20User%20Story%20Flowchart.pdf )

******It's also my first year in front end development******

here's the netlify link for preview

https://memorymap-js.netlify.app/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Memory Map</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />

        <!---- LEAFLET LIBRARY -->

        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha256-sA+zWATbFveLLNqWO2gtiw3HL/lh1giY/Inf1BJ0z14="
            crossorigin=""
        />

        <!---- FONT AWESOME -->
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />

        <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha256-o9N1jGDZrf5tS+Ft4gbIK7mYMipq9lqpVJ91xHSyKhg="
            crossorigin=""
        ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="popup">
            <i class="close-popup fa-solid fa-x"></i>
            <h1>Insert your memory about this place</h1>
            <input
                type="text"
                class="input"
                placeholder="Please insert your memory here"
            />

            <button type="submit" class="add-memory-button">Add memory</button>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="left-container">
                <h1 class="info-left-h1">
                    Click on the map to create a memory location!
                </h1>
                <div class="memory-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
html body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.left-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.left-container {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    background: rgb(34, 193, 195);
    background: linear-gradient(
        0deg,
        rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%,
        rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 100%
    );
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: fit-content;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}

.memory-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: fit-content;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.memory-div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.memory-div {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    width: 90%;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 60px;
    background: rgba(255, 213, 0, 0.08);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3.6px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3.6px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 213, 0, 0.19);
    margin: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.memory-div:hover {
    background: rgba(152, 128, 6, 0.08);
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.paragraph-left {
    display: flex;
    width: 72%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 14px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.fa-sharp {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    justify-content: center;
    position: sticky;
}

#trash {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: white;
}
#trash:hover {
    color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
}

.popup {
    width: 79vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    left: 30%;
    background: rgb(2, 233, 237);
    background: linear-gradient(
        0deg,
        rgb(0, 251, 255) 0%,
        rgb(244, 172, 18) 100%
    );
    opacity: 90%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.popup input {
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 240px;
    top: 280px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #fdbb2d;
    color: white;
}

.popup h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 160px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    top: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    opacity: 100%;
}

.add-memory-button {
    width: 220px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 420px;
    background-color: rgba(253, 187, 45, 1);
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.popup button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(247, 168, 0);
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.popup button:active {
    background-color: rgb(194, 132, 0);
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.close-popup {
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    left: 940px;
    top: 40px;
}
.close-popup:hover {
    color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
#map {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}

/* PHONE RESPONSIVE */
@media (max-width: 420px) {
    html body {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    .container {
        z-index: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    #map {
        z-index: 0;
        display: flex;
        height: 50%;
        width: 420px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .left-container {
        display: flex;
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .info-left-h1 {
        font-size: 10vw;
        position: relative;
        left: 20%;
        top: 100px;
        height: 10px;
    }

    .popup {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .close-popup {
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        left: 60%;
    }

    .popup h1 {
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 10vw;
    }

    .popup input {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        top: 200px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .add-memory-button {
        position: relative;
        left: 100px;
        top: 40%;
    }

    .memory-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

/* TABLET RESPONSIVE */

@media (min-device-width: 540px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    html body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    .left-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }

    .info-left-h1 {
        font-size: 5vw;
    }

    .popup {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .popup h1 {
        font-size: 6vw;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .popup input {
        left: 12%;
    }
    .add-memory-button {
        left: 36%;
    }

    .close-popup {
        font-size: 60px;
        left: 90%;
    }
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
}
```

```javascript
"use-strict";

//------------------SELECTORS-------------------

const popUp = document.querySelector(".popup");
const input = document.querySelector(".input");
const Button = document.querySelector(".add-memory-button");
const closePopUp = document.querySelector(".close-popup");
const infoText = document.querySelector(".info-left-h1");
const memoryContainer = document.querySelector(".memory-container");
const memoryDiv = document.querySelector(".memory-div");
const mapHTML = document.getElementById("map");
const map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
}).addTo(map);

//-----------------------FUNCTIONS---------------------------

let latGeo = [];
let lngGeo = [];
let markers = [];

let divId = -1;

// MAP CLICK

const markerClick = function (e) {
    divId++;

    infoText.style.display = "none";
    const lat = e.latlng.lat;
    const lng = e.latlng.lng;

    const marker = new L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
    markers.push(marker);

    popUp.style.display = "block";

    latGeo.push(lat);
    lngGeo.push(lng);
};

// MEMORY CLICK SUBMISSION

const submissionClick = function () {
    const value = input.value;

    if (!value) {
        alert("Please insert a memory before submitting :) ");
    } else if (value.length > 25) {
        alert("Keep the memory up to 25 letters maximum. ");
    } else {
        memoryContainer.innerHTML += `  <div class="memory-div" id="${divId}">
       <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
       <p class="paragraph-left"> ${value} </p>
       <i class="fa fa-trash trash" id="trash" ></i>


   </div>`;

        popUp.style.display = "none";
        input.value = "";
    }
};

// MEMORY ENTER SUBMISSION

const submissionEnter = function (e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        const value = input.value;

        if (!value) {
            alert("Please insert a memory before submitting :) ");
        } else {
            memoryContainer.innerHTML += `  <div class="memory-div" id="${divId}">
       <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
       <p class="paragraph-left"> ${value} </p>
       <i class="fa fa-trash " id="trash" ></i>


   </div>`;

            popUp.style.display = "none";
            input.value = "";
        }
    }
};

// CLOSE POP UP

const popUpClose = function () {
    popUp.style.display = "none";
    input.value = "";
    map.removeLayer(markers.pop());
    latGeo.pop();
    lngGeo.pop();
    divId--;
};

// MOVE MAP TO GEOCOORDS

const moveMapToGeo = function (e) {
    if (e.target.className === "memory-div") {
        const arrayNumber = e.target.id;
        map.flyTo(new L.LatLng(latGeo[arrayNumber], lngGeo[arrayNumber]));
    } else {
        return;
    }
};

// DELETE MEMORY DIV & MARKER

const deleteMarkerAndDiv = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id === "trash") {
        const divID = e.target.closest("div").getAttribute("id");
        map.removeLayer(markers[divID]);
        document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "none ";
    }
};

// NIGHT MODE

//-----------------------EVENT LISTENERS---------------------

//------MAP CLICK ----------

map.on("click", markerClick);

//------Form Click Submission ----------

Button.addEventListener("click", submissionClick);

//------Form Enter Submission ----------

input.addEventListener("keypress", submissionEnter);

//------Pop Up Close ----------

closePopUp.addEventListener("click", popUpClose);

//------Move Map To Memory Div Coords ----------

document.addEventListener("click", moveMapToGeo);

//------Delete Memory ----------

document.addEventListener("click", deleteMarkerAndDiv);
```

Comment: Hm the flowchart link gives me a 404 page not found - is it in a private github repository?

Comment: @ccchoy I’ve just made it public now.

Comment: When you say "pure" CSS - does that mean that it's regular ol CSS / or is that a framework or something? I'm trying to figure out what the JS is here for -

Comment: Ah NM. I misread it. So, - regular JS and regular CSS - gotcha.

Comment: The current question title is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2):

This is code review, right! So - in this case - I'll just comment along with your code. :)

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* you absolutely need this - look it up */
}

html body { /* there's no need to say "any body inside of an html"
    /* you can just use 'body' as the selector */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100vw; /* it's already 100% width by default */
    height: 100vh; /* should likely be min-height */
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; /* these should likely be taken care of by a css-reset (I use meyer-reset) */
}

.container { /* container is a bad name. everything is a container */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* these are suspect - why are they needed ? */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.left-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.left-container { /* left-container is a bad name - what if it's not left at a different break point? also / I don't know what it's for. Is it a 'sidebar' - or what is its actual purpose? name it with that */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    background: rgb(34, 193, 195);
    background: linear-gradient(
        0deg,
        rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%,
        rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 100%
    );
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%; /* likely not needed... based of of a previous decision */
    max-height: fit-content; /* maybe needed */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2vw; /* probably should use clamp here for min/max */
    color: white; /* should be a custom-property for site-wide colors */
    position: relative;
    top: 40%; /* sounds scary! */
    text-align: center;
}

.memory-container { /* again... "container" doesn't help me know what this is */
    width: 100%; /* aren't all block-level elements width:100% already? */
    max-height: fit-content;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.memory-div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; /* this sounds like bad news */
}
.memory-div { /* even worse name than container */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    width: 90%;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 60px;
    background: rgba(255, 213, 0, 0.08);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3.6px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3.6px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 213, 0, 0.19);
    margin: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.memory-div:hover {
    background: rgba(152, 128, 6, 0.08);
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.paragraph-left { /* again - keep the visual out of the selector names */
    display: flex;
    width: 72%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; /* centered paragraphs? */
    font-size: x-large; /* probably don't use these... */
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 14px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.fa-sharp { /* I'd suggest SVG sprite over fa as it seems to break a lot */
    display: flex;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    justify-content: center;
    position: sticky;
}

#trash { /* avoid ids in your CSS */
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: white;
}
#trash:hover {
    color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
}

.popup {
    width: 79vw; /* this seems very 'magic' and is suspect */
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    left: 30%;
    background: rgb(2, 233, 237);
    background: linear-gradient(
        0deg,
        rgb(0, 251, 255) 0%,
        rgb(244, 172, 18) 100%
    );
    opacity: 90%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.popup input {
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 240px; /* this positioning seems scary and likey to break */
    top: 280px; /* how about using grid instead */
    border: 2px solid #ffffff; /* border width and color should be custom -properties */
    background-color: #fdbb2d;
    color: white;
}

.popup h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 160px; /* brittle */
    top: 20%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; /* already on the body in your case */
    opacity: 100%; /* why? */
}

.add-memory-button { /* could also be button.add-memory  - but either way - this was a good selector because I knew what it did / but is the "add" really relevant - should there be a global .button type class? */
    width: 220px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute; /* there is probably a better way for this */
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 420px;
    background-color: rgba(253, 187, 45, 1);
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.popup button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(247, 168, 0);
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.popup button:active {
    background-color: rgb(194, 132, 0);
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.close-popup { /* these should probably be scoped to the pop-up module or something so that they aren't global */
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    left: 940px;
    top: 40px;
}
.close-popup:hover {
    color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
#map {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}

/* PHONE RESPONSIVE */ /* I HIGHLY suggest working from small screen up - instead of the larger screen and then putting in these overrides */
@media (max-width: 420px) {
    html body {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    .container {
        z-index: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    #map {
        z-index: 0;
        display: flex;
        height: 50%;
        width: 420px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .left-container {
        display: flex;
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .info-left-h1 {
        font-size: 10vw;
        position: relative;
        left: 20%;
        top: 100px;
        height: 10px;
    }

    .popup {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .close-popup {
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        left: 60%;
    }

    .popup h1 {
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 10vw;
    }

    .popup input {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        top: 200px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .add-memory-button {
        position: relative;
        left: 100px;
        top: 40%;
    }

    .memory-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

/* TABLET RESPONSIVE */ /* I HIGHLY recommend not targeting devices like this - and instead just building up organically from small>medium>large etc -- and it'll be easier to write and maintain */

@media (min-device-width: 540px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    html body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    .left-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }

    .info-left-h1 {
        font-size: 5vw;
    }

    .popup {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .popup h1 {
        font-size: 6vw;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .popup input {
        left: 12%;
    }
    .add-memory-button {
        left: 36%;
    }

    .close-popup {
        font-size: 60px;
        left: 90%;
    }
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
}
```

Here's a streamlined way to think about it from small screens first -
https://codepen.io/perpetual-education/pen/rNrWOVo?editors=1100

Comment: Now I'm looking over your front end. I can see that my fears that the absolute positioning was going to be trouble - were real. I think you can get the layout you have with much less code - and in a way that won't break without that. I'll make a CodePen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/perpetual-education/pen/rNrWOVo?editors=1100

Comment: "avoid ids in your CSS" Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: CSS selectors can be made up of element names and ids and classes and data attributes and anything you want. But having some simple conventions can keep things clear for the developers. For me, I use only classes to style things - and then I can use IDs only for anchor links. There can only be 1 id of each value per page and I see a lot of new developers using say, #map - many times in a for each loop or something. But I also use other attributes for styling. There's no 100% best way. I used to use rel attributes exclusively - for JavaScript identifiers. Whatever you do, just stick to a plan.